# Visual Studio 2017 Report Viewer overrides jquery theme

Tags: visual-studio-2017, report-viewer2016

I upgraded a project from VS2015 to VS2017 Community Edition and eventually got reports working again. In particular, I have **Microsoft Rdlc Report Designer for Visual Studio v14.1** and **Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms v140.340.80** installed.

Everything works: I can edit reports in the designer, and I can display reports at runtime.

The problem: When I display a report, the report viewer overrides the CSS in the jQuery theme my project uses. My buttons, for example, change style to look *very* different than intended. Inspecting the web page shows the CSS is being overridden by this:

```
http://localhost:52800/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&Version=14.0.340.80&Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Styles.jquery-ui.min.css
```

That is, it looks like the report viewer is linking to a default jQuery theme. How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue - to work around the issue you might want to include the RVC on a separate page and embed via iFrame to sandbox the jQuery UI CSS.

Comment: Thanks, I'm guessing your suggestion would work, although iFrames are notoriously problematic for browser compatibility. Also, we have over 100 reports, and we certainly aren't going to redesign all of those pages. At present, we've had to back down to earlier versions of VS and reports, and hope this will be fixed soon so we can try again.

Comment: The RS team is about to release an update to the Report Viewer Control that addresses the jQuery conflict issues. If you would like to test out the changes a release candidate with the changes is up at -
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms/140.705.117-rc

Comment: Thank for the tip, Rhys!